# Low upload speed - but only with a specific router/pc couple

Tags: networking, router

I'm not really sure this is the best place to ask. If it isn't, feel free to suggest or move it to another more appropriate place.

I set up a small NAS with an Orange PI zero (a small SBC with ethernet and a USB port). The problem is that I'm experiencing low upload speeds from it (i.e. its outgoing connections).

Now, I have a TPLINK TD-W8970 v3 router. I have two laptops connected through two of its gigabit ports, while the oPI is connected to a third gigabit port. Speed tests are done with a samba transfer (big file) and with iperf3; no big differences between the two tests.

The transfer speed between the two PCs is roughly 1Gb/s, so the router is capable of handling the speed and also the PCs are ok.

If I try to upload something on the oPI from one PC (either by samba or testing with iperf3) the max speed is around 93-94 Mb/s. This is in line with the 100Mb/s ethernet port, so everything is as expected.

If, on the other hand, I try to download something from the oPI, the maximum speed is at most 2.4 Mb/s (around 300kB/s). This is pretty annoying, since it takes ages to download something from it.

But now comes the strangest thing: if I disconnect the oPI from the router, and connect it to a small chinese 3G router wifi configured as access point and set up to forward the ports to the ethernet port, the speed I get is about 40Mb/s in both directions (ok, since the wifi connection is at 54Mb/s).

For reference, the 3g router is like this one:

[image: 3g router wifi]

I tried changing the ethernet port on the router, but without any success.

At the moment, I'm not really sure where the problem can be. It looks like the problem is neither of the oPI or the cable (with the 3g router everything works fine), neither of the router (since changing the port should have affected the behavior). I think it is a configuration issue, but why?

Thank you for any suggestion on how to proceed

EDIT:

For clarification sake, here is some diagrams showing connection and speed:

```
Legend:
iperf server ==link==> ... ==link==> iperf client
speed


PC ==ethernet==> ROUTER ==ethernet==> PC
900-950Mb/s

PC ==ethernet==> ROUTER ==ethernet==> oPI
93-94Mb/s

oPI ==ethernet==> ROUTER ==ethernet==> PC
2.4Mb/s

PC ==ethernet==> ROUTER ==wifi==> 3G ROUTER ==ethernet==> oPI
40Mb/s

oPI ==ethernet==> ROUTER ==wifi==> 3G ROUTER ==ethernet==> PC
40Mb/s
```

Comment: What do you see with iPerf? You can use it to test in BOTH directions.

Comment: When you changed the router did you change the Ethernet cable connecting to the Pi in the process?  It's possibly an issue with the send pair on a cable?

Comment: @Appleoddity Maybe it is not clear from the question. The iperf data is what I wrote in the text. PC->PC about 900-950Mb/s, oPI->PC 2.4Mb/s, PC->oPI 94Mb/s, oPI->PC wifi 40Mb/s, PC->oPI wifi 40Mb/s. Here I wrote iperfClient->iperfServer

Comment: @davidgo no, I used the same cable. I also tried with another cable between the router and the oPI and it didn't change

Comment: It sounds like the difference is not really between two routers but between a WiFi and wired connection. Would that be correct? If you use a different wired router does it work faster? I believe the router model is a red herring and that really you're just seeing poor handling of incoming traffic on the wired connection on the oPi. oPis are not known for having excellent quality drivers...

Comment: @BenFranske I added some diagrams to better show the connections. The problem is that with two PCs I get almost 1Gb/s, so the transfer speed of the router is ok on ethernet. On the oPI the port seems ok too, since with the 3G router it can arrive to 40Mb/s. So why doesn't it arrive to at least 40Mb/s on wired connection only? The port is the same....